# ARM overflow flag

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I [read here](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/19/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-5/), that the overflow flag might also be set in certain cases. Trying out the following sample of code :-

```
.global main
.func main

main:
mov r0, #4026531839
mov r1, #-1
sub r0, r0, r1
os is_set
mov r0, #17
bx lr

is_set:
mov r0, #71
bx lr
```

I got an error message that said the following :-

```
carryflagsub.s: Assembler messages:
carryflagsub.s:8: Error: bad instruction `os is_set'
```

Isn't `os` the instruction used to test if the overflow flag is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `os` instruction in ARM instruction set. However, to test if the overflow flag is set you can use conditional execution of instructions, like that.

```
bvs is_set
```

You can learn about conditional execution in [ARM reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABEHFEF.html).

Answer (score 0):

By `os` I assume you mean `vs`.

If you want to branch on the `vs` condition, the instruction is `bvs`.